# Convert datetime to another datetime format

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

How do I convert this datetime?

```
[23/Sep/2013:21:18:00 +0200]
```

to

```
23/Sep/2013 21:18:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a proper date/time content in the cell, you just need to 'format' the date time to:

```
dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

Just right click on the cell - Format Cell - Under "Numbers" tab - Custom and use the above.

EDIT: 
Since the incoming format is very restrictive, we need to get creative, and it does ends up as 3 step process:

1. Converting that text into usable text (removing the [], the excess :, and the +0200 at the end)
2. Converting the text into proper date/time value
3. Formatting the date/time properly (as above)

**First**
You need an intermediary cell to hold the "usable text", and use this code below (Assumption is that the date/value text is in A1 AND the text format are static and does not change throughout your data):

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A1,2,11)," ",MID(A1,14,8))
```

This will return

```
23/Sep/2013 21:18:00
```

But this is a "text" format, and not yet usable. - Assumption that this value is in A2

**Second**
Convert the above text into proper date/time format by using DATEVALUE and TIMEVALUE as below:

```
=DATEVALUE(A2)+TIMEVALUE(A2)
```

Now it is in a proper Date/Time format - but may be not the exact format that you wanted. Follow step 3, above my edit to do your custom date/time format.

Reference (and credit): David Zemens from Stack Overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089263/excel-string-to-date

Hope this helps.